# Using locate to find a directory

Tags: find

I use *locate* all the time to find files that I know the name of, *locate* is very fast and I love that. For recently created files *find* is great, normally with recently created files I know where basically they were created so I don't have to search my entire file system.

When I've forgotten the location of a directory however neither find nor locate seem ideal.

Locate always spits out far too much information because every file within a directory is also a match for locate. For instance if I was searching for a directory named log somewhere on my file system *locate log* would return tons and tons of results. If I do the same thing with find, *find / -name log -type d* find takes minutes to run and spits out all sorts of permissions errors every time it encounters a folder it can't read.

Is there a better way?

Answer: So I'm sticking with grep until I find something else:

```
locatedir () {
    for last; do true; done
    if [[ $last == *\/* ]]
    then
        locate $@ | grep "${last}\$"
    else
        locate $@ | grep "/${last}\$"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A way (I suspect there may be a better way) is to use grep to return only the those paths which end in your folder name :

```
locate foldername | grep /foldername$
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use the option `--regex` (`-r`) of [`locate`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/locate.findutils.1.html):

```
locate -r '/log$'
```

Comment: Yes (+1). `locate` has its own built-in regex capablility:  `-r` or `--regex` ... for full range of options see: **info locate**

Comment: I knew there must be a better way!

Comment: So short and it works smoothly. Great contribution! Another reason to learn/master **regular expressions**

Comment: You don't need the two `'` in this case: `locate -r /log$` is enough.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried:

`locate /home/insertusernamehere/*/filename`?

or

`locate file | grep -i '^/home/.*/examplesubdirectory'`?

or any variation of such?

Comment: This answer shows that `grep` isn't necessary, and as seen in the first suggested option, neither are regexps.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is

```
locatedir () {
    locate "$*" | while read line
    do 
    if [ -d "$line" ] ; then echo $line ; fi
    done
}

locatedir $*
```

Comment: If you can explain what changes you have made it will be helpful for other too.